# Parse attribute from xmlns based elements with SAX in Android

Tags: android, xml-namespaces, sax

i'm trying to parse this [xml file](http://achdre.freehostia.com/example4.xml) but i can't find a way to parse the url attribute from
`<media:thumbnail width="66" height="49" url="http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/41447000/jpg/_41447190_exomars66esa.jpg"/>` element. I tried with the following `startElement` method in my handler class

```
public void startElement(String Uri, String localName, String qName, 
Attributes atts) throws SAXException { 
if (localName.equals("channel")) {
        this.in_channel = true;
}else if (localName.equals("item")) {
        this.in_item = true;
}else if (localName.equals("title")) {
        this.in_title = true;
}else if (localName.equals("media:thumbnail")) {
        String attrValue = atts.getValue("url");
        item.setLink(attrValue);
       }
}
```

I also tried `if (localName.equals("media")` but didn't work out
I can parse an element like this`<link url="http://achdre.freehostia.com/example.xml"/>` but not the one I posted above. thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the qName.

From the [doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/xml/sax/ContentHandler.html#startElemen):

localName - The local name (without prefix), or the empty string if Namespace processing is not being performed.

qName - The qualified name (with prefix), or the empty string if qualified names are not available.

The local name basically strips off the name space, so if you wanted, you could also do 'thumbnail' which would also match.

Comment: @demian83 If you write **thumbnail** instead of '(localName.equals("media:thumbnail"))' , it will work.